# Typescript for (let i of someArray) doesn't work in IE11

Tags: javascript, typescript

Does anyone know why, in TypeScript with a compilerOptions targeting ES6, I used the following syntax to iterate the array?  It worked on both Edge and Chrome, but not IE11. It complained a ; is missing on the beginning line of the for loop.

```js
for (let thisId of changedIDs) {
...
}
```

When I changed it to the plain old Javascript for loop, then it worked on all 3 browsers.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < changedAnswerIDs.length; i++) {
...
}
```

Comment: IE11 support for ES6 is not something you should rely on. If you need to support IE11 I'd bump your target down to es5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `for...of` loop. IE has limited support for ES6 syntax. As @Phix mentioned in the comment, you should change the compiler target to ES5 or earlier to support IE.

Comment: No, the issue is the `for ... of`. `let` and `const` are supported  just fine.

Answer (score 1):

IE 11 doesn't fully support ES6. You can use Babel to compile to ES5.
Babel: https://babeljs.io/ or any other compiler really.
You can also use this link to see more about compatibility: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/